# What is a seed in the process of Ethash

Tags: mining

For mining purposes one needs to generate a seed. I read some articles but still did not understand where this seed comes from. How is calculated, or what it is about? I found this on Ethereum wiki github:

```
def get_seedhash(block):
 s = '\x00' * 32
 for i in range(block.number // EPOCH_LENGTH):
     s = serialize_hash(sha3_256(s))
 return s
```

Can anyone explain this code to me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethash divide hash calculation in epochs, with each epoch being 30000 blocks, all blocks in the same epoch start with the same seed.

For epoch 0 the seed is `'\x00'*32 = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'`.

For epoch `N` the seed will be the sha3 of the seed of the previous epoch `N-1`.

For example in epoch 1 the seed will be `sha3('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000') = '0x290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e563'`.

Comment: So in an epoch there are 30.000 blocks?

Comment: and is there any sources for reseraching?

Comment: Yes, each epoch as 30,000 blocks. To research you can look at some clients implentations, like go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum or parity.

Comment: Can we have  a chat-room discussion?

Comment: If you have any question you can ask here, when I've time I'd take a look.